# Relation of orbital radius with linear velocity of satellite

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, satellites

If a planet is going around the sun in a circular orbit , and if suddenly (impulsively) it's orbital radius was increased , what would happen to the linear velocity of planet (With reason)

Comment: What do you mean by "suddenly"? The change in the trajectory has to come from an acceleration in the first place. Or do you mean to ask what the relationship between radius and orbital velocity is for circular orbits? If that's it, demonstrate some research effort and explain why you can't calculate that yourself.

Comment: Yeah , I am asking for the relation between linear velocity and orbital radius , I have an answer but am not sure if it is correct , would be glad if you helped !

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember the formula for centripetal force in circular motion, which in this case is due to gravity. As a refresher:

$$F= \frac {m_2v^2}{r} $$

Where $F$ is the centripetal force which is due to gravity and is given by:

$$F = G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

$G$ is the universal gravitational constant $6.67408 × 10^{-11} m^3 kg^{-1 }s^{-2}$

$m_1$ is the mass of the sun

$m_2$ is the mass of the planet

$r$ is the orbital radius

$v$ is the orbital velocity

I hope that now you can answer your own question.

Clue: Orbital velocity is inversely proportional to orbital radius.

Comment: So it would decrease , right ? (Equating centripetal force and gravitational force , v ^ 2 is inversely proportional to 'r') , or am I still doing something wrong ?

Comment: Correct, the further objects are out from a gravitational point mass the slower they will move. I think it is a consequence of the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Curiously, to move to this higher, slower orbit, one must speed up, *twice*...